# Insertion of values into a MySQL table referencing another table for a foreign key

Tags: java, mysql

I've currently got the below query which I'm wanting to use to insert two strings and a foreign key. However as I'm passing the string for the foreign key I want to get the key at the time of the insertion so the record would actually read as:

"All Asia Asset Cp", "AAA", 1

Below is the String I use:

```
    String sql = "INSERT into constituent " + 
            "(constituent_name, constituent_ticker, sector_id) values (\""+ 
            constituent.getConstituentName() + "\",\"" +
            constituent.getConstituentTicker() + "\"," +
            "(select id from sector where sector_name = \"" + constituent.getConstituentSector() + "\"))";
```

Below is the query.

```
INSERT into constituent (constituent_name, constituent_ticker, sector_id) 
  values ("All Asia Asset Cp","AAA",
     (select sector.id from sector where sector_name = "General Financial Sector"))
```

However, I get the below error and I'm stumped. Any ideas?

```
Unknown column 'sector.id' in 'field list'
```

Running the query as is in phpMyAdmin works.

Running it from java using the below throws the error:

```
    //Initialize insertValues
    insertValues = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

    //Attempt to add the values into the database
    try {
        insertValues.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "createConstituent ", e);

    }
```

DDL For the sector table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sector` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sector_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sector_url` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

DDL For the constituent table:

```
CREATE TABLE `constituent` (
  `constituent_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `constituent_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `constituent_ticker` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `constituent_isin_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `constituent_currency` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `sector_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`constituent_id`),
  KEY `sector_id` (`sector_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Post the DDL for the sector table, it seems as though this column does not exist.  By the way are you sure its not `sector_id` instead of sector.id

Comment: have you tried using id instead of sector.id?

Comment: show your sql string please

Comment: @Farax. Yep tried doing that. Same problem.

Comment: Make sure your inner query returns one result, if name field is unique or you add limit 1 to the end of the inner statement then it should be enough.

Comment: @KevinBowersox DDL Posted.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind string added near the top

Comment: I`m not sure but I think you quote the resulting id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone.

The unknown column was because the application was pointing to the correct DB which did not have the column, and I was attempting to insert manually through PHPMyAdmin into the incorrect DB which had the column.

I'm an idiot.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sector.id, could you try only with id. Could it be?

```
INSERT into constituent (constituent_name, constituent_ticker, sector_id) values ("All Asia Asset Cp","AAA",(select id from sector where sector_name = "General Financial Sector"))
```

Comment: The same problem exists if I do it this way too.

Answer (score 0):

try out this query..

```
    INSERT into constituent (constituent_name, constituent_ticker, sector_id) 
    values ("All Asia Asset Cp","AAA",
    (select id from sector where sector_name = "General Financial Sector"))
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d65bb/1)

Answer (score 0):

The way your using is not the way to insert 
use **executeUpdate()**

```
//Initialize insertValues
insertValues = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

//Attempt to add the values into the database
try {
    insertValues.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {

    Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "createConstituent ", e);

}
```

Comment: Same problem exists I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The unknown column problem seems to have been fixed by surrounding the column name with single quotes so that the line now reads:

```
INSERT into constituent (constituent_name, constituent_ticker, sector_id) values ("All Asia Asset Cp","AAA", (select 'id' from sector where sector_name = "General Financial Sector"))
```